# Cannot redeclare function error - but function only declared once

Tags: php

I am getting an error "cannot redeclare sortProperties()" however I'm struggling to find where this is declared twice.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sortProperties() (previously declared in
>   actions/query-properties.php:185) in actions/query-properties.php on
>   line 190

So it says it is being declared on line 185 and then reclared on 190. This is odd because those are the beginning and ending lines of the function:

```
185: function sortProperties($a, $b) {
186:      if ($a["specs"]["bedroom_number"] === $b["specs"]["bedroom_number"]) {
187:          return ($a["info"]["status"] !== "let") ? -1 : 1;
188:      }
189:      return ($a["specs"]["bedroom_number"] > $b["specs"]["bedroom_number"]) ? -1 : 1;
190:  }
```

The function is called by `usort()` higher up in this file. Is this likely to be affecting it?

```
160: usort($property_list, "sortProperties");
```

Comment: Sounds like you have done something like "include('actions/query-properties.php')" in more than one place. You could switch to "include_once" (or require_once).

Comment: that means the file query-properties.php is included twice (at least) --- add something like `echo "a";` before the declaration of the function to found what appends